# Javascript counter variable code throwing cannot read property exception

Tags: javascript, arrays, counter, dom-events

I've built a little website with a carousel image slider.  The image slider has a next and previous button that when clicked, trigger the next or previous image with some corresponding text.  When the page first loads, however, if the first button clicked is the previous button, the slider throws a cannot read property exception.  The error is below.  I've also put all of the html, css and js in a code block below.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Imagedes' of undefinedmoveLeft @
>    ShowcaseWebsiteTest.html:257(anonymous function) @ ShowcaseWebsiteTest.html:277m.event.dispatch @ jquery-latest.min.js:3m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-latest.min.js:3

```
<html>
<title>Showcase Website</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<style>
header {
      width:100%;
      background-color:lightblue;
      text-align:center;
      padding:5px;
  }
  /*Use of the child selector Combinator*/
  header > h1 {
      color: black;
}
  /*Use of Pseudo-Class*/
  p::first-letter {
      font-size: x-large;
}
  /*Use of the Navigation Bar*/
  nav {
      line-height:30px;
      background-color:#8f8f8f;
      height:1500px;
      width:100px;
      float:left;
      padding:5px;
      position: relative;
  }
  /*Pseudo-Class*/
  a:visited {
      color: #00BDA0;
}
  /*Using Box Model, Border, Outline, Margin, Padding, Dimension, Float*/
  section {
      height:350px;
      width:100%;
      padding:10px 0 30px 2px;
      border: 3px solid gray;
      margin: 0px 1px 5px 25px;
  }
  /*Using the "display: none" property to hide a previous title*/
  h1.hidden{
      display: none;
  }
  /*Using Positioning*/
  article.art1 {
      height:350px;
      width:350px;
      float:center;
      padding-top:100px;
      padding-left:50px;
      position: relative;
      top: 125px;
      left: 85px;
  }
/*Using Positioning*/
  aside {
      height:350px;
      width:350px;
      float:right;
      padding-top:10px;
      padding-right:150px;
      position: relative;
      top: 45px;
      left: 45px;
      right: 50px;
  }
  footer {
      background-color:lightblue;
      color:white;
      clear:both;
      text-align:center;
      padding:5px;
  }

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);

html {
border-top: 5px solid #fff;
background: #58DDAF;
color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 200px;
list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background: #ccc;
text-align: center;
line-height: 300px;
}

button.control_prev, button.control_next {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
padding: 2% 2%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
background: #2a2a2a;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 10px;
opacity: 0.8;
cursor: pointer;
border:solid transparent;
}

button.control_prev:hover, button.control_next:hover {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

button.control_prev {
border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

button.control_next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.active{
    color:red;
}
.imageDes{
    color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <h1>Text</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
       <a href="">Home</a>
      <br><a href="">How To</a>
      <br><a href="">Additional</a>
      <br>
    </nav>

    <section class="section3">
      <h1>Text</h1>
      <p>
        Text
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
      </ul>
    </section>


<div id="slider">

  <button class="control_next">></button>
  <button class="control_prev"><</button>
  <ul>
     <li class="active" data-des="Image 1">SLIDE 1</li>
     <li data-des="Image 2" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
     <li data-des="Image 3">SLIDE 3</li>
     <li data-des="Image 4" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
<div class="imageDes"></div>

<footer>
Name Here
    </footer>


  </main>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var dataJson=[{"Imagedes":"Description for Image one which can be so long that it might extend upto 2 lines in most of the cases and that has to be rendered on image change"},
    {"Imagedes":"Description for Image two which can be so long that it might extend upto 2 lines in most of the cases and that has to be rendered on image change"},
    {"Imagedes":"Description for Image three which can be so long that it might extend upto 2 lines in most of the cases and that has to be rendered on image change"},
        {"Imagedes":"Description for Image four which can be so long that it might extend upto 2 lines in most of the cases and that has to be rendered on image change"}]

var index=0;
$('.imageDes').text(dataJson[0].Imagedes);
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
   }, 3000);
 });

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');

    });
    if(index<=0)
        index=slideCount;
    else
        index--
    $('.imageDes').text(dataJson[index].Imagedes);
};

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });

    if(index+1>=slideCount)
        index=0;
    else
        index++
     $('.imageDes').text(dataJson[index].Imagedes);

};

$('button.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
});

$('button.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle.net or using the code editor here would be great

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, I see `Imagedes` and `imageDes`

Comment: means your index is out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the max too high.

```
index=slideCount
```

needs to be

```
index=slideCount-1
```

Comment: your code specifices the moveRight function, but the problem is with the moveLeft function.  Also I've tried your suggestion and it doesn't work.  Yes, it's an out-of-range problem, but where?  I played with it some, but still it eludes me...

Comment: Because you set it to index=slideCount; which is greater than the last index

Comment: The second part of your answer fixed it (the first part did not, in case you want to edit your answer).  I've tested the second part and it works beautifully.  Thanks so much for the assistance, I really appreciate it.